# ArcGIS 10.1 SP 1 install on Windows Server 2012 questions

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, windows-server-2012

I will be setting up ArcGIS server 10.1 SP 1soon and I have a few questions before I start this.  I have looked at the Web Adapter and the ArcGIS install guides but wanted to get some input.

1.Has anyone been installing on Windows Server 2012?  I will be installing ArcGIS 10.1 SP1 and the Web Adapter on a separate 2012 servers.  Have there been any problems with this that people have ran into?  Should I just stick with 2008 R2 or just go with 2012?

2.I see the ArcGIS server needs IE 7 min, and looks like it can go up to 9.  Will this software work with IE 10 though?

3.What ports am I going to need open between the Web Adapter server and the ArcGIS server, 6443?  Is 6080 just for the server to World if I am doing the web and GIS all on 1 server?

4.If I am using SSL and HTTPS over port 6443, should I be using certs?

Comment: Please read the [faq] and post only one question per thread.

Comment: Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lot of specific information is available on web help hence most of the time I have provided the direct links and I am using always using web help first ,easy resource to understand first..

According to your questions,

1.Has anyone been installing on Windows Server 2012? I will be installing ArcGIS 10.1 SP1 and the Web Adapter on a separate 2012 servers. Have there been any problems with this that people have ran into? Should I just stick with 2008 R2 or just go with 2012?

**Ans :** Please check [system requirements for ArcGIS Web Adaptor (IIS) for server 2012](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/install-guides/arcgis-server-web-adaptor-iis/10.1/index.html#//01nz00000015000000).  You can install ArcGIS Server and web adopter on separate machines . I have installed at my end ( I am using Win. Server 2008 R 2) not sure for 2012 but there will be no problem.

2.I see the ArcGIS server needs IE 7 min, and looks like it can go up to 9. Will this software work with IE 10 though?

**Ans:** Yes it will work with IE 10.0. Please check [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/system-requirements/10.1/index.html#//01510000006q000000)

3.What ports am I going to need open between the Web Adapter server and the ArcGIS server, 6443? Is 6080 just for the server to World if I am doing the web and GIS all on 1 server?

**Ans:** According to me port 6080 & 6443.For more details please check [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//015400000537000000) for details

4.If I am using SSL and HTTPS over port 6443, should I be using certs?

**Ans:** Not sure but You need to generate Certificate. Please click [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0154000005wq000000) for more details

Please check this and let us know if you have any problem..

thanks..

Comment: Thanks for the links.  I don't have the link to the doc I was looking at before but I didn't see IE10 on the list.  What are you using port 6446 for?

Comment: @Chadddada I am sorry..regarding question 3 please read port 6443 instead of 6446. When SSL is enabled, ArcGIS Server uses port 6443 by default.